# Quantum invariants of 2-knots

Tags: mathematical-physics, knot-theory, quantum-field-theory, quantum-groups, knot-invariants

I'm looking for a status report on analogues of quantum invariants of knots, for the 2-knots (homotopy classes of spheres / other Riemann surfaces embedded into 4-manifolds).

**Background**

I'm mostly interested in this subject from the point of view of theoretical physics. One of the beautiful inspiring results from the end of 20th century was the [discovery](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.cmp/1104178138) by E.Witten that the Jones polynomial (and its generalizations) admit a manifestly topologically-invariant, 3-dimensional definition in terms of expectation values of quantum physical observables corresponding to the knots, in a quantized version of the Chern-Simons field theory.

Naively, by analogy, invariants of 2-knots can be obtained by considering quantum observables corresponding to 2-surfaces in some kind of generally covariant 4-dimensional theory. Examples also include quantum General Relativity (though I'm fairly certain nobody was able to define it up to date).

**Question**

I'm looking for a quick overview of known 2-knot invariants, including those which admit manifestly topologically invariant 4-dimensional definitions in terms of quantum physical observables in some 4-dimensional generally covariant physical theory. Or, for a unequivocal statement that those haven't been discovered yet.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have a 4d TQFT with surface operators (2-knots). Then it can be decategorified to a 3d TQFT with line operators (1-knots); that is, let's say $M$ is a 3-manifold and $L\subset M$ is a 1-knot. Then for any 4d TQFT $Z_4$ with surface operators, $Z_3(M,L):=Z_4(M\times S^1,L\times S^1)$ should be a 3d TQFT. Therefore, in this sense, your question is about categorifying 3d TQFTs to 4dTQFTs.

There are several knot polynomials which have been categorified (i.e. lifted to a 4d TQFT) in the past few decades. The first was [Khovanov homology](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/9908171), which is a categorification of Jones polynomial, giving invariants for knot cobordisms (2-knots). Similarly, there are [categorifications of colored Jones polynomials](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0302060) and the [HOMFLY-PT polynomial](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401268). These mathematical constructions depend on the projection of links, so they are not manifestly 3-dimensional.

There is a [proposal by Witten](https://arxiv.org/abs/1101.3216) describing Khovanov homology as a space of BPS states. This physics based description of Khovanov homology is manifestly 3-dimensional, in the similar spirit as Witten's paper on the Jones polynomial 30 years ago.

While many of these knot invariants have been categorified, so far they are all done in $\mathbb{R}^3$ (or $S^3$). Considering the fact that Jones polynomial can be generalized to an invariant of links inside any 3-manifolds (Witten-Reshetikhin-Turaev (WRT) invariant), we would like to categorify those invariants as well. However, categorifying quantum 3-manifold invariants is still incomplete and largely open. There are [some recent proposals](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.06567), but I guess still a concrete categorifiation is far from being done.